# Arch Dark Theme & Qt Creator

Tags: qt, archlinux, qt-designer, kde-plasma

I am trying to edit the Arch Dark theme so that the coloring of certain text is white/light colored because it is barely readable when there is black text on a dark blue background. So in my case, I use Qt Creator often to design GUI's and create applications but when you open it, it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOQ2C.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5xXu.jpg

As you can see there is black text on the dark backgrounds in the home screen and on the project screen, I am unsure whether these colors have to be changed in Qt or through the theme files themselves but is it possible to change them to white or a lighter color of my choosing.

Comment: How is archlinux not a relevant tag? This is a Plasma KDE theme for Arch Linux (which is the linux distribution I am using)

Comment: Oh ok I understand thank you, I will put those tags.